# hp laserjet 1300 will not print

Tags: windows-xp, laser-printer, hp-laserjet

I installed hp laserjet 1300 and it is visible by WIN XP SP3 (Control Panel - Printers and Faxes).

Green light is on - it should be ready.

But it will not print anything. No error is displaying,

In system try the icon is showing that a document is pending to print, but - that`s all.

Please help.

Comment: Couple things to try first. Did you install driver from cd or website or just plug in? If you have not installed official drivers from manufacture, start there.     In the printers window(control panel - printers faxes) is the printer set to default? right click on printer and select set as default.   Right click on my computer and select manage.   select device manager from left.  Does your printer have a yellow or red symbol next to it?  We can progress further after these steps

Comment: @sethbuffington, drivers are downloaded from official hp site. Printer is set as default. There is no yellow quest mark in device manager. I restarted OS and after print command from word or firefox now the icon in system try shows a red symbol that there is some problem. I canceled the pending documents and the icon is gone away. So, communication with the printer seems ok, but - there is no printing.

Comment: Is trying printer on another pc and option to you? or you can try to print from a linux live cd(boot entire linux os from cd without installing or touching files) Slitaz is small and quick to get.  knoppix is a bit bigger and flashy with effects but  has alot of hardware support.  We need to narrow it down between printer or windows problem.  Also just because. try another usb cable if possible. let me know what happens

Comment: @sethbuffington, when i downloaded drivers it was assigned as lj1500-1300. Now I see in Control Panel the printer is assigned as 1300 PCL6. Maybe matters.

Comment: @sethbuffington, i will try now on another comp. please wait

Comment: Once you have installed drivers they will be in your system even if you delete the device in device manager.  you can try to delete from device manager, then click the top item "computer" and above that is a icon that says search for new hardware. it will find printer and reinstall drivers.(hopefully the right ones)

Comment: @sethbuffington, the identical behavior on another PC. I have no Linux CD.

Comment: With other HP printers I've installed it was very important **not** to install the drivers before hooking up the printer. Instead the directions had to be followed exactly, which said to not plug the printer into the computer until the installer prompts you to so.

Comment: What martineau says above is true about plugging in hp printers. it can be fixed though by following comment 3 up about deleting from device manager.  If you have any blank cd's you can download and burn any copy of linux you choose. 99% of linux distros are free. If its out of your comfort level no big deal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most often when this happens, Windows has marked your printer as "Paused" or "Offline". To fix these, go to the "Printers and Faxes" control panel item, and right-click on your printer, make sure that "Use printer online" is checked and click on "Resume printing" if visible.

More detailed instructions can also be found here: http://www.inktechnologies.com/blog/brother-printer-paused-or-offline/.

Comment: try this method, If that does not work either try a factory reset on the hp printer

Comment: Solved. But how - I'm not sure. I tried so many thing. Anyway - Thanks to EveryOne !